# Преждевременное срабатывание p:outputPanel deferred="true" deferredMode="visible" в java web primefaces

Tags: java, веб-программирование, primefaces, xhtml

Есть таблица p:dataTable, внутри которой расположен тег <p:outputPanel deferred="true" deferredMode="visible">. Сделано это для того, чтобы отследить, какие записи таблицы пользователь просмотрел, а какие еще нет. Он листает вниз, deferredMode="visible" срабатывает и выполняется метод бина. На primefaces 7.0 всё работало внутри таблицы прекрасно, обновился до primefaces 8.0 , внутри таблицы p:outputPanel стал срабатывать сразу, даже на тех строках, которые не проскролены и на экране еще не видны. Я проверил, вне таблицы всё работает правильно, скролю страницу вниз и только тогда срабатывает p:outputPanel. Что я упустил, возможно, какие-то изменения или есть возможность иначе решить эту проблему.
Вот код страницы

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
 <h:head>
   <title>my_editor</title>
 </h:head>

<h:body styleClass="mainBody">
<div class="mainContainer">
    <h:form id="formId" styleClass="mainForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        <div class="content">
            <p:dataTable id="tableRefact" value="#{myBean.myEntities}" var="entity"
                         rows="5" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" first="0" lazy="true"
                         widgetVar="newsTable" editable="true" paginator="true"
                         paginatorPosition="top"
                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}
                                         {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,50">
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{myBean.onRowEdit}"
                        update="tableRefact"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{myBean.onRowCancel}"
                        update="tableRefact"/>
                <p:column style="width:150px">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <p:graphicImage value="#{myBean.myImage}" styleClass="graphicImage">
                                <f:param name="myUrl" value="#{entity.url}" />
                            </p:graphicImage>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="200"
                                             value="#{myBean.addedMyImageUrl}"
                                             placeholder="Enter image url..."
                                             styleClass="inputElement">
                            </p:inputTextarea>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{entity.name}" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="200"
                                             value="#{entity.name}"
                                             placeholder="Введите заголовок..."
                                             styleClass="inputElement">
                            </p:inputTextarea>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>

                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{entity.description}" style="font-weight: normal"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="7" cols="200"
                                             value="#{entity.description}"
                                             placeholder="Введите описание..."
                                             styleClass="inputElement">
                            </p:inputTextarea>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>

                    <a href="#{entity.url}" target="_blank" style="color: #1063aa">#{entity.url}</a>

                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="Founded:" styleClass="underlineWithBold"/>
                            <h:outputText value=" #{entity.founded}" style="font-weight: normal"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputTextarea rows="8" cols="200"
                                             value="#{entity.founded}"
                                             placeholder="Введите Founded..."
                                             autoResize="true"
                                             styleClass="inputElement">
                            </p:inputTextarea>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:rowEditor/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:outputPanel id="mapContainerId" deferred="true" deferredMode="visible">
                                #{myBean.saveAction()}
                            </p:outputPanel>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:row>

                </p:column>



            </p:dataTable>
        </div>
    </h:form>
  </div>
 </h:body>
</html>
```